# Slider to change continually with slide gesture

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, slider

I have a slider control with `Minimum=20` and `Maximum=100`, `SmallChange=1` and `LargeChange=10`. 
When the user slides the slider, it slides to some distance, and stops, i.e It does not slide continually with the user's finger. 
I want it slide till the user removes the finger. What mistake am i making?
This is the xaml of my slider

```
   <Slider x:Name="slider"
            Margin="0,12,-4,94"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Maximum="100"
            Minimum="20"
            SmallChange="30"
            LargeChange="10"
            Value="26"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Width="74"
            ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"
            MaxHeight="710" />
```

Update: 
I am not doing anything important in the Slider_ValueChanged method, well anyways here it is

```
   try
        {
            if (recentIndex == -1)
                textBox1.FontSize = slider.Value;
            else
            {
                lstTextBox[recentIndex].FontSize = slider.Value;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
```

it is of no importance in this context

Comment: Can you show the code for Slider_ValueChanged ? Everything else is ok and the slider should work as expected.

Comment: i am not doing much in the Slider_ValueChanged method.. well, anyway i am posting because you asked.. 
try
            {
                if (recentIndex == -1)
                    textBox1.FontSize = slider.Value;
                else
                {
                    lstTextBox[recentIndex].FontSize = slider.Value;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }

Comment: You said it "slides to some distance" what distance is that? Is it different each time?

Comment: There must be something else wrong, I've tested the slider on a blank page and it works ok.

Comment: it changes by 1 when sliding. but I have tried changing the SmallChange value, but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to be using a gesture service/detection (like below)?

```
<Toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <Toolkit:GestureListener GestureCompleted="GestureListener_Tap"/>
</Toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

Thes do somehow interfere with the (smooth)scrolling function of sliders.
If so, you should try to solve it by replacing your gesture detection with a instance of the `ManipulationStarted, ManipulationDelta or ManipulationCompleted` Event.

[Gesture options which won't mess up sliders...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967546%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)